# Is there a command for rename the second duplicated data in stata?

Tags: duplicates, rename, stata, recode

I have a list of data with three variable, ADDRESS, FOODCODE and Gr, that consist 1752 household addresses and type of foods they consumed and the amount of food by gram.
these data have duplicated record, for example I have two similar address, with similar foodcode, but different gram.
Now I want to rename the second similar address to a new address in stata.

```
input double Address int(foodcode gr)
12401295014 11111  4000
12401295014 11111 10000
12501308608 11112 20000
12501313708 11112 10000
11701202105 11115  5000
11701202105 11115 10000
end
```

Comment: What do you want to rename it to?

Comment: rename the second address that repeated to Address (1). for example 12501308608(1)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem for `rename`, which is about renaming variables, and nothing to do with changing the data otherwise. Although you don't ask for it, it might be useful for you to set up a new variable

```
bysort address: gen id = _n
```

Changing the values of `address` so that the same household gets different values is likely only to make analysis more difficult.